Is there workaround to mirror a buffer to a file (similar to indirect buffer)?
I am familiar with indirect buffer capability of emacs.
From doc string:

An indirect buffer shares the text of some other buffer, which is
called the base buffer of the indirect buffer. In some ways it is a
buffer analogue of a symbolic link between files.


The text of the indirect buffer is always identical to the text of its
base buffer; changes made by editing either one are visible
immediately in the other. “Text” here includes both the characters and
their text properties. But in all other respects, the indirect buffer
and its base buffer are completely separate. They can have different
names, different values of point, different narrowing, different
markers, different overlays, different major modes, and different
local variables.

The procedure is as follows:
M-x make-indirect-buffer RET base-buffer RET indirect-name RET

But there is a restriction:

An indirect buffer cannot visit a file.

Question:
Is there a mechanism in emacs or a package that permits to have a an indirect buffer identical to the text of a base buffer with extra requirement that indirect buffer can be a real file on the disk (e.g., indirect buffer can visit a file)?
Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2196/ and Why use indirect buffers?

Can you elaborate? In particular, why are you looking for this - what do you want to do with it? (So far, sounds a bit like it might be an X-Y question. I.e., "That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.")
