# Enable mode association with backup files as well

Tags: major-mode, association-lists

I want to enable mode association with backup files as well. E.g., if I backup my `my-markdown.md` file as `my-markdown.md.orig` or `my-markdown.md.lastweek` etc, I want them still be associated with the markdown mode. This is how I'm trying to fix it:

```
 (use-package markdown-mode
-  :mode ("\\.\\(txt\\|markdown\\|md\\)\\'" . markdown-mode))
+  :mode ("\\.\\(txt\\|markdown\\|md\\)\\(\\'\\|\\.)" . markdown-mode))
```

It was working fine before my hack, but now neither the `.md` files nor the `.md.lastweek` are associated.

*UPDATE*, for the record, for all my questions, I gather all the answers to [here](https://github.com/suntong001/emacs.d).

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in using the `auto-mode-alist` and defining the backup file extension names with your `markdown-mode`?

Comment: @lawlist I believe the `use-package` macro is doing exactly that -- it creates `auto-mode-alist` entries based on the specific `:mode` config.

Comment: You have not escaped the final `)` in your regex string. Maybe you meant this: `\\.\\(txt\\|markdown\\|md\\)\\(\\'\\|\\.\\)`?

Comment: One unrelated tip: With `use-package :mode` you don't need to specify the actual mode name unless it differs from the package. So for markdown you could just do this: `(use-package markdown-mode :mode "\\.\\(txt\\|markdown\\|md\\)\\(\\'\\|\\.\\)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were on the right track but your regular expression does not escape the final `)` character, like so:

```
"\\.\\(txt\\|markdown\\|md\\)\\(\\'\\|\\.\\)"
```

As a general tip, you can test out Emacs regular expressions using `regexp-builder`. Put some example text in a scratch buffer, say:

```
foo.md
foo.md.lastweek
foo.md.orig
foo.mdnomatch
```

Then do `M-x regexp-builder`. This opens a RE-Builder buffer where you can put in the regular expression and see what matches. (One note if you use this approach to test your expressions: `\\'` only matches the end of the content being tested, not the end of a line. Using `$` would be easier to test in this way.)

Comment: Ahh! The last ) character! Thanks, and for the tip for `regexp-builder` too!

Comment: For another approach, see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2654/780. You can configure `auto-mode-alist` to drop an extension and then continue to look for matches. This would allow you to append `.orig` to any file name and allow Emacs to still recognize the original extension.

Comment: My backup file extension is actually time based. E.g., for today, it'll be `foo.md.2015-01-10`, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the [regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html), `"\\.\\(txt\\|markdown\\|md\\)\\(\\'\\|\\.)"` is the problem.

**try this**

This regular expression should match `.txt`, `.markdown`, `.md`, `.md.lastweek`, and `.md.orig` file extensions.

```
"\\.\\(txt\\|markdown\\|md\\([.]\\(lastweek\\|orig\\)\\)?\\)"
```

**an alternative method**

Explicitly [define the major mode inside the files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) by placing the following [markdown comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885980/951721) at the top of each file.

```
[//]: # ( -*- mode: markdown; -*- )
```

The comment should be hidden when you post it.

As a test, I explicitly inserted the [example comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/7247/edit) to the top of this answer.

I recommend using the alternative method because it provides the flexibility and convenience to assign the correct major mode as needed.

For example, what if you *try* another extension pattern in the future:

> e.g.
>          .md.2015011000.your_username
>          .md.2015011001.my_username

If you like the new pattern, then you can always update the regex later and you won't risk break your current mapping during testing.

This also provides a safe method to test out new major modes, e.g. *super-special-markdown-mode*, before remapping the extensions in emacs.

Hope that helped!