# How to set major mode according to buffer name for non-file buffers

Tags: org-mode, buffers, major-mode

Some buffers are created by Emacs and is set in fundamental mode, like the `*Org-Babel results*`. I think it is more convenient to set them in special mode, which can be closed with key `q`. How do set the mode for those automatic buffers or if the name contains `*`?

Lawlist and Drew's comments below show possible ways to do it, what I want is a special-display buffers for some buffers with `*...*` names. The appropriate way of course is to find the function for creating the buffer and change it in the package, but it doesn't suit everybody.

Since `special-display-regexps` is obsolete, can anyone help me on an `display-buffer-alist` with a custom function to look for `*Org-Babel Results*` and set it to special mode?

Comment: Do you want to set the mode or bind a key?

Comment: It would be better, in my opinion, to locate each of the functions responsible for creating the buffers in the first place and enable the custom mode at that point -- i.e., modify the functions directly responsible. Anything else is just an after-the-fact-hack (in my opinion).  It is really easy to find with grep -- i.e., just look for the name of the buffer in the source code, and things like `get-buffer-create`, `display-buffer`, `pop-to-buffer`, etc.

Comment: For example, my first grep led me to `ob-core.el` and a line of code that looks like:  `(pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*Org-Babel Results*"))`  Now, I don't use that library and have no idea what it is used for, but I'll bet my lunch money that either that line or something similar to that line would be a prospective location to make modifications.  A new function can be created in the `.emacs` file by having a preceding require statement -- e.g., `(require 'ob-core)` and then the new function with the *same* name  -- i.e., `(defun org-babel-open-src-block-result (&optional re-run) . . .`

Comment: For example, after `(pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*Org-Babel Results*"))` or after the next line -- i.e., `(delete-region (point-min) (point-max))` -- you could add a line `(with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*Org-Babel Results*") (enable-my-custom-major-mode))`  In my opinion, this is much more precise/localized than customizing the `display-buffer-alist` with a custom function to look for `*Org-Babel Results*`, which is another possibility, but I don't recommend broad brush approaches like that.

Comment: The question is unclear, IMO, and risks being closed for that reason. Are you looking for special-display buffers (e.g. setting `special-display-regexps` to `("[ ]?[*][^*]+[*]")`, for buffers with `*...*` names? Are you looking for buffers whose mode inherits from `special-mode`, so that `q` quits them? There's no guessing what you are really asking for? What happened to software people being able to *specify* something? ;-)

Comment: Personally, I don't find the question unclear, he wants special-mode to be activated on org-results  buffers (and other buffers with similar name).

Comment: @godblessfq The question in your title (major mode for non-file buffers) is a duplicate [of this one](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2497/50). Would you consider editing your question and title to be more specific to org-results buffers?  (because I don't think any of the answers on the other question would work on the org-results buffer)

Comment: One way would be to advice/redefine the functions that create the buffers of your interest and add `(special-mode)` at the right location in the elisp code after the buffer is created.

Comment: [Example from the `paradox` package](https://github.com/Malabarba/paradox/blob/a0283bd7485eb422ab4aecfef5fb8d2fa8dd5aff/paradox-execute.el#L141) of what I am talking about above.

Comment: The following link contains a complex example using the `display-buffer-alist` on a let-bound basis to examine (among other criteria) the buffer name matching certain predefined regexp -- the comments indicate how to set this globally using `setq` -- the thread title is **How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame**:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is another solution which is more elegant

```
(setq-default major-mode
  (lambda ()
  (if (db-regexp-match-p special-buffer-regexp (buffer-name))
      (special-mode)(fundamental-mode))))
```

Comment: This solution *may* cause problems somewhere down the line because the C-source code has `major-mode` set up as a **symbol**, *not* necessarily a function (although it could be the **symbol** of a function).  It so happens that `fundamental-mode` is a function defined within `simple.el`

Comment: Even though I have enabled both solutions, I still don't have the latex output buffer (C-c C-l) in special mode. The buffer name is \*filename output\*.

Comment: I posted my comment underneath the other answer as it relates to just that one.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to lawlist. I finally got it working.

```
(defun db-regexp-match-p (regexps string)
  (and string
       (catch 'matched
         (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t))
           (dolist (regexp regexps)
             (when (string-match regexp string)
               (throw 'matched t)))))))
(defvar special-buffer-regexp
  '("[*].*results.*[*]" "[*].*out.*[*]")
  "Regexp of special mode buffer names")
(defun set_special_mode (buffer alist)
  (interactive)
  (if (db-regexp-match-p special-buffer-regexp (buffer-name buffer))
  (with-current-buffer buffer 
      (special-mode))))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '(".*" . (set_special_mode)))
```

Comment: `(setq display-buffer-alist '((".*" . (set_special_mode))))` -- it *may* [?] be possible to use `add-to-list` instead of `setq`, but you are missing two (2) pairs of parentheses  and a period in either event.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you! But it appear to work before the fix. Apparently I need to learn more elisp. :-)

Comment: If you look at your edit history, you'll see that you had it essentially right (just with a more restrictive regexp that isn't really needed since the `db-regexp-match-p` is doing the work), but then you accidentally broke it when you used `add-to-list` -- at that point in the edit history, you *lost* a period and you *lost* a couple of pairs of parentheses.

Comment: The latex output buffer doesn't work even after the fix.

Comment: You can use *either* of the following examples:  `(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '(".*" . (set_special_mode)))` **or** `(setq display-buffer-alist '((".*" . (set_special_mode))))`  You can test either example by evaluating `(display-buffer (get-buffer-create "*filename output*"))`  If running a test with `add-to-list`, be sure to return the variable `display-buffer-alist` to a `nil` value so that you don't end up stacking your tests one on top of the other -- e.g., evaluating `(setq display-buffer-alist nil)` will reset the variable to a value of `nil`.

Comment: You can use `M-x describe-variable RET display-buffer-alist RET` to check the value of the `display-buffer-alist`; or, `C-h v`

Comment: The latex output buffer generated by C-c C-l still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to duplicate the basic test indicated above -- i.e., evaluating in a `*Scratch*` buffer the expression?:  `(display-buffer (get-buffer-create "*filename output*"))` -- you can place the cursor at the end of that expression and type `C-x C-e` and it should pop open a buffer in Special Mode.  You will need to pay particular attention to the two examples in my previous comment -- the number of surrounding parentheses are different depending upon whether you use `setq` or `add-to-list`.  After we establish that the basic test works as expected, then you can broaden your debugging.

Comment: I was able to duplicate the basic test. Maybe the latex output buffer set the mode differently.

Comment: You have successfully completed the first step of your journey by creating a working draft that can easily be tested.  The next step in debugging would be to open up the latex source code and examine it to ascertain why the behavior is not as you expect.  Take a crack at figuring it out -- if you need help, then I believe that should be a new question since your basic setup is now complete.  Keep in mind that my original recommendation remains the same -- modify the original functions at the source instead of using this particular method to set `special-mode`.